Firebase Realtime - Flutter - Listen async
I need help as I need to call asysc on my listener somewhere and if my date updates my app freezes.
I am sure it's due to my call to the Firestore not done correctly
late List<Data> sensorList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tooltipBehavior = TooltipBehavior(enable: true);
    //_activateListerner();
    getSensorData();
  }

  void getSensorData()  {
     _database.child(_path).orderByKey().limitToLast(10).onValue.listen((data) {
      debugPrint("${data.snapshot.value}");
      final sensorData = Map<String, dynamic>.from(
          data.snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>);
      sensorData.forEach((key, value) {
        final nextData = Data.fromRTDB(Map<String, dynamic>.from(value));
        debugPrint("${nextData.data}");
        sensorList.add(nextData);
        debugPrint("${sensorList[0].data}");
      });
      setState(() {});
    });
  }


